# how can I carry all my installed libraries from one Ubuntu installation to other

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, libraries

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 which includes many libraries that use for my work. I would like to carry all of those to another clean Ubuntu installation. Is there any tool helps for the process or any idea how to do it?

Comment: Are they installed manually, or through apt-get/aptitutde?

Comment: Most of them apt-get

Comment: Then read here, http://www.howtogeek.com/111989/how-to-sync-quickly-reinstall-applications-on-ubuntu/